# onBeforeRequest is not called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm debugging why requests are not being blocked by my chrome extension. Inspecting the network tab, it seems like there are two requests going out, one is blocked and one is not:
[image: network request tab]

Using breakpoints, I also noticed that the event handler for onBeforeRequest is only called once. How can I block the first request as well?

The event handler is:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    // set badge text to indicate that a help widget is available
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: "HELP", tabId: details.tabId });

    if (isDisabled) {
      return { cancel: false }; // this should return from the function (details) level
    } else {
      return { cancel: true };
    }
  },
  {
    urls: [
      // ...
      "*://js.usemessages.com/*",
      // ...
    ],
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

This issue only appears with Chrome, not with Firefox. The complete extension code [can be found here](https://github.com/bcye/Hello-Goodbye/tree/master/Chrome).

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/1012977 fixed in Chrome 82. Try adding `,"extraHeaders"` after `"blocking"`.

Comment: @wOxxOm doesn't fix it :/

Comment: If your code works in Chrome Canary then it must be the bug I linked.

Comment: @wOxxOm yup works in Canary, weird.

Comment: It's not weird - it's a bug which was fixed in Chrome 82 whereas Chrome Canary is 85.

Comment: @wOxxOm with weird, I meant that it is weird that your proposed solution doesn't solve it.